# Which part of this websocket result is the binary protobuf data?

Tags: javascript, websocket, protocol-buffers

I am receiving protobuf data from a remote host over a websocket. I know how to decode the protobuf in JS using [Protobuf.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js) but I cannot determine which part of the result coming through the websocket is in fact the protobuf data I need to decode. Attempting to decode the entire result gives me the JS error:

> Cannot wrap null or non-object

If I log to console the object returned from the websocket, it looks like this:

[image]

I've tried decoding various things like `e.data` (where `e` is the total result returned) but not sure if I'm going about this the right way.

What part of this holds the actual protobuf content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the data is in `.data`, and appears to be represented as a [`Blob`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#blob). Working with blobs in javascript is not trivial. To get an *object* from that, you would need a javascript protobuf implementation that accepts a `Blob` and returns the deserialized object.

Comment: Well, it [looks quite simple](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/wiki/Builder#decoding-from-an-arraybuffer-a-bytebuffer-a-node-buffer-or-a-base64-string)…

Comment: @Bergi fair enough; I wasn't aware of that implementation, but yes, that should work nicely; that of course simply moved the complexity down to the library, but that is kinda the *point* of libraries ;p